# Powershell not parsing cmd command correctly

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm curious how powershell is parsing this.

This does not work (I get a wrong syntax error from the exe)

& dnscmd 'sdfsdfs /RecordAdd my.domain test123 a 1.1.1.1'

In order to get it to work I had to do this:
cmd /c 'dnscmd sdfsdfs /RecordAdd my.domain test123 a 1.1.1.1'

I thought I was using to invoke-expression cmdlet correct here why doesn't it work?

Comment: `&` is not an alias for `Invoke-Expression`. See [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) for more about how to execute programs with Powershell

Comment: [This article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type the command.

```
dnscmd sdfsdfs /recordadd my.domain test1233 a 1.1.1.1
```